# Microsoft Graph API: Get MailboxSetting of other user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I try to edit Out Of Office of other user.
In example, User "A" is connect in the application and try to edit User "B" Out Of Office. But I get "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again".

The Credentials of user A is correct and I can edit my own MailboxSetting.

I use this permissions: "User.Read", "User.Read.All", "MailboxSettings.ReadWrite", "Calendars.ReadWrite".

I use this URL: "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/B/mailboxSettings" with PATCH method.

I try different user profile, but nothing works.

Someone already try to do this and success ?
If yes, what is the permissions or user's profile ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I tried the mailboxSettings by coding and Graph Explorer, both return the same value as you posted. So it should be a bug from the PG side. You can report bug by the Github issue list.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I found an Issue in the GitHub -> https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3289

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An issue is open on the Microsoft Graph GitHub

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3289